# Overlapping scroll

Tags: scroll

I have a couple of sections, each containing a few sub-sections. Something like this:

- Section A

  - Subsection 1
  - Subsection 2
  - Subsection 3
- Section B

  - Subsection 1
  - Subsection 2
  - Subsection 3
- ...

When the user scrolls the bottom of the last sub-section into the viewport that sub-section should stop scrolling.
Then while the user scrolls further the next section should scroll in above it and overlap it.
I'd like the overlapping section to scroll like normal, with the exception that it goes above the previous one.

I hope this awesome gif can explain it a little better than words can...

[image: Example of the effect]

I've been looking at solving this with jQuery and checking how far the document has been scrolled and trying to apply position fixed at the right time and position. But haven't been able to get the effect I'm after. I'll have to admit that my jQuery skills isn't the best and that I'm stuck.

Does anyone have a pointer in the right direction for me on how to solve this?

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "parallax scrolling" search that in Google

Comment: I know about parallax scrolling, and have been Googling a lot, but I haven't been able to find a solution for this particular effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate leaving unanswered questions on StackOverflow, that's why I'm answering a question 3 years after. If you want to run a function when the user sees something when he scrolls, there is a jQuery plugin called NoobScroll (just google it or go on [this link](https://noobscroll.js.org)) Then, you should checkout the `scrollOn()` function, or the `scrollProgress()` function on the documentation (wiki on GitHub) to trigger an animation, and I hope you'll solve your problem

Comment: Your plugins seems nice, I'm saving it for future reference! The problem I had is forgotten since long, and I have no possibility to test this since the project isn't active any longer. Looks like your plugin solves the problem I had though, so I'm accepting this as an answer!